# Upgrading react-redux for react 18 breaks when using createRoot

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

We updated all packages in our legacy project to the latest versions:

- react/react-dom: 18.2.0
- react-redux: 7.2.0 => 8.0.5
- redux: 4.0.5 => 4.2.0
- redux-thunk: 2.3.0 => 2.4.2

By themselves, everything works. When we try to use the `createRoot` from 'react-dom/client', redux stops working.

No errors or warnings are shown in dev mode and tests render empty bodies.

We have a mix of class components using connect, mapToProps... and functional with useSelector.

All components using Redux stop working as they should. But only when using new `createRoot`. Using the legacy way, they work as normal.

Tables don't render what they should be rendering, or render old values. Tests break showing empty bodies...

Comment: I'm afraid "stops working" isn't very much information. Also, note that if you're using React 18, you _should_ be using React-Redux v8, which has been updated to properly work with React 18.

Comment: @markerikson yes, thank you. I've updated the question. Basically, it seems I can update the packages and it works. But as soon as I change to the new way of starting React, everything using Redux stops working.
It's been a while that we had updated React, but had to left the legacy start because of Redux. We are trying again, and it seems to work fine even with the updated dependencies, the problem only shows when changing the entry to use the new architecture.

Comment: Can you put together a minimal project that shows this issue? Or, create a Replay ( https://replay.io/record-bugs ) of this happening? For clarity, I'm a Redux maintainer, and my day job is at Replay building a time-travel debugger. I'd be happy to try to take a look, but I'd really need to be able to investigate the code and see what's happening.